# Mule: sending an input stream payload (from file) along with file metadata to http outbound endpoint

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I have an input stream payload with data from a file. The file can be very big. I'm sending the input stream to an http/https outbound endpoint. However, I'd like to also send metadata with the contents of the file, such as the file name and possibly other key/pair values in the post request.

If I have an input stream, and also a few strings which I want to send as a single post data, what would I need to do with Mule on the payload in order to have them all sent properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want is to have `inbound properties` available as `outbound` so that they are send along with the message payload.

You may copy individual property if you just care about some like

```
 <set-property propertyName="originalFilename"  value="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"/>
```

or you could copy all of them at once like

```
<copy-properties propertyName="http.*" doc:name="Copy All HTTP Headers"/>
```

You can do this before calling http `outbound endpoint`